# Splitting up a string - php

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach, explode

I have an array called $result, which is shown below:

```
array(1) 
    { ["response"]=> array(3) 
        { [0]=> array(1) 
            { ["list"]=> array(2) 
                { ["category"]=> string(6) "(noun)" 
                ["synonyms"]=> string(27) "chelonian|chelonian reptile" } 
            } 
          [1]=> array(1) 
            { ["list"]=> array(2) 
                { ["category"]=> string(6) "(verb)" 
                  ["synonyms"]=> string(57) "capsize|turn turtle|overturn|turn over|tip over|tump over" } 
            } 
          [2]=> array(1) 
            { ["list"]=> array(2) 
                { ["category"]=> string(6) "(verb)" 
                  ["synonyms"]=> string(29) "hunt|run|hunt down|track down" } 
            } 
         } 
    }
```

I am trying to access the ["synonyms"] element, and split each word and store it in its own string, or perhaps an array of all the words. You can see the words are separated by the `|` symbol.

I have tried the following code, which did not work (results did not display, so explode did not work) :

```
$i=0;

foreach ($result["response"] as $value) 
{ 
 foreach ($value["list"]["synonyms"] as $temp)
  {
  $alternative[$i] = explode ("|", $temp);
  $i++;
  }

}

//OUTPUT THE RESULTS

$j=0;

foreach ($alternative as $echoalternative)
{
echo $j.": ".$echoalternative;
$j++;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks guys.

Comment: did not work how? no results? exploded wrong? crashed your server? kicked your dog?

Comment: Sorry @Marc B.. I added a note, I will be more careful in future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to iterate over the string in your interior foreach. Try

```
foreach ($result["response"] as $value) 
{ 

  $alternative[$i] = explode ("|", $value["list"]["synonyms"]);
  $i++;


}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, this results in the following (I am trying to implement the next step now!)

`array(3) 
{ [0]=> array(2) 
 { [0]=> string(9) "chelonian" 
   [1]=> string(17) "chelonian reptile" } 

 [1]=> array(6) 
{ [0]=> string(7) "capsize" 
  [1]=> string(11) "turn turtle" 
  [2]=> string(8) "overturn" 
  [3]=> string(9) "turn over" 
  [4]=> string(8) "tip over" 
  [5]=> string(9) "tump over" } 

 [2]=> array(4) 
 { [0]=> string(4) "hunt" 
   [1]=> string(3) "run" 
   [2]=> string(9) "hunt down" 
   [3]=> string(10) "track down" } 

}`

Comment: @Jenny What exactly is your desired end result?

Comment: Hey Stephen, Just saw your comment now. I am attempting everything at the moment, a bit of background: The synonyms are generated by a user search. The ultimate aim is turn each synonym into a list like shown on the dogpile.com search page (after searching for something.. in the left navigation bar...the synonyms would be listed under..`are you looking for?`) I think it would be best to have the synonyms in a single dimensional array?

Comment: @Jenny But since you have multiple words, each with their own synonyms, a multidimensional array seems necessary unless you want to store the synonyms packed together into a string(which you clearly don't). Perhaps an array of arrays, with each key being the word, and each value its array of synonyms?

Comment: Thanks StephenTG. Its great to have the words split. I will figure out what to do next (hopefully, if not, Ill be back here!)

Answer (score 3):

To create an array of single dimensional arrays (given that you have three groups in your original array), you can do the following:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($arr['response'] as $key => $value){
    $syns = explode('|', $value['list']['synonyms']);
    foreach ($syns as $key2 => $value2){
        $out[$key][] = $value2;
    }
}
```

To access the single dimensional array for the group of synonyms with index 0, just do the following:

```
var_dump($out[0]);

Array(
    [0] => chelonian
    [1] => chelonian reptile
)
```

If you just want to display the synonyms, you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($arr['response'] as $key => $value){
    $syns = explode('|', $value['list']['synonyms']);
    foreach ($syns as $key2 => $value2){
        echo $value2.', ';
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Output:

```
chelonian, chelonian reptile,
capsize, turn turtle, overturn, turn over, tip over, tump over,
hunt, run, hunt down, track down,
```

However, if you want to include that in the original array, you can do this:

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function (&$e, $k){
    if (preg_match('#[\w\|]+#', $e)){
        $e = explode('|', $e);
    }
});
var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array(
    [response] => Array
            [0] => Array(
                    [list] => Array(
                            [category] => Array(
                                    [0] => (noun)
                                )
                            [synonyms] => Array(
                                    [0] => chelonian
                                    [1] => chelonian reptile
                                )
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array(
                    [list] => Array(
                            [category] => Array(
                                    [0] => (verb)
                                )
                            [synonyms] => Array(
                                    [0] => capsize
                                    [1] => turn turtle
                                    [2] => overturn
                                    [3] => turn over
                                    [4] => tip over
                                    [5] => tump over
                                )
                        )
                )
            [2] => Array(
                    [list] => Array(
                            [category] => Array(
                                    [0] => (verb)
                                )
                            [synonyms] => Array(
                                    [0] => hunt
                                    [1] => run
                                    [2] => hunt down
                                    [3] => track down
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: From what Jenny tried, it seemed like they wanted the split synonyms in a separate array

Comment: Hey guys, I am attempting everything at the moment, a bit of background: The synonyms are generated by a user search.                       The ultimate aim is turn each synonym into a list like shown on this page (left navigation bar...are you looking for?)... http://www.dogpile.com/info.dogpl.t10.3/search/web?fcoid=417&fcop=topnav&fpid=27&q=turtle&ql=  .... I think it would be best to have the synonyms in a single dimensional array?

Comment: Thanks Pe de Leao, if I could accept multiple answers I would, Stephen Just got there a few mins earlier :P.. You have both been a great help :)

Answer (score 2):

The following refactored code should resolve the issue

```
$i=0;

foreach ($result["response"] as $value) 
{ 
// print_r($value);
$temp = $value["list"]["synonyms"];
// echo $temp;
 // foreach ($value["list"]["synonyms"] as $temp)
  // {
  $alternative[$i] = explode ("|", $temp);
  $i++;
  // }

}

//OUTPUT THE RESULTS

$j=0;

foreach ($alternative as $echoalternative)
{
print_r($echoalternative);
echo $j.": ".$echoalternative;
$j++;
}
```